# Whole app crashes when cancel download button is pressed

Tags: android

I have a button that starts a download showing a progress dailog. The progress dailog has a cancel button that stops the download. But when the cancel is clicked the download stops but whole app crashes without staying on mainactivity
Q) how to stop this from happening and stay on the mainactivity
2) how to delete the partial downloaded file
Here is the progress dailog code

```
DownloadFileFromURL cdrt = new DownloadFileFromURL();

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.setButton("Cancel", new CancelOnClickListener());
            pDialog.show();
            return pDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
private final class CancelOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        MainActivity.this.finish();
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
        if(cdrt.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
        cdrt.cancel(true);}
}
```

**asynctask**

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);

            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/download/downloaded.jpg");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);


    }

}
```

**logcat**

```
12-12 11:37:10.791 25155 25155 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main

12-12 11:37:10.791 25155 25155 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.mycompany.myapp2, PID: 25155

12-12 11:37:10.791 25155 25155 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no dialog with id 0 was ever shown via Activity#showDialog

12-12 11:37:10.791 25155 25155 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.missingDialog(Activity.java:3461)

12-12 11:37:10.791 25155 25155 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.dismissDialog(Activity.java:3446)
12-12 11:37:10.791 25155 25155 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.mycompany.myapp2.MainActivity$DownloadFileFromURL.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:170)
12-12 11:37:10.791 25155 25155 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.mycompany.myapp2.MainActivity$DownloadFileFromURL.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java)
12-12 11:37:10.791 25155 25155 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
12-12 11:37:10.791 25155 25155 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
```

Comment: Are you passing correct parameter to dismissDialog() ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line.

```
        MainActivity.this.finish();
```

from your method.. `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {`

As your are finishing your activity when your cancel method gets called. And it tries to handle view which not exists. So it should be something like this.

```
private final class CancelOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

    if (cdrt != null &&  cdrt.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)) {
        cdrt.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I remove that line only the dailog closes but the download is still in progress in background. When I press the download button again the progress dailog appears withe the download happening

Comment: try out this updated code. I think it is because it's not matching if(cdrt.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) condition.

Comment: But the download is still going on in the background

Comment: Yeah did it as you said

Comment: @Droidwala Still the same, the download is continued

Comment: @user5524159 i am sorry i read your question again..and as suggested in the answer you shouldn't be calling `MainActivity.finish()` method if you want to stay in same activity on cancel..And the above code should cancel your asynctask..Not sure why that is continuing download..are you sure asynctask is not getting cancelled? Post your asynctask code in the question..

Comment: @Droidwala Posted my asynctask code in the edit please have a look

Comment: @user5524159 try to put `Log.d` statement in the if condition of this answer's code and see if `asynctask.cancel(true);` is getting called or not?

Comment: debug it. If it is going to this condition or not. As it should work. May be some other issue in defining or handling your async task.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to dismiss a dialog that you don't have access to. Dismiss the dialog inside the AsyncTask class. If you dismiss the dialog inside your activity then it will crush

```
     pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.setButton("Cancel", new CancelOnClickListener());
        pDialog.show();
```

Should be inside the AsyncTask Class

Comment: I am dismissing the dailog under asynctask only

Comment: for what i've seen you have separate methods for showing and dismissing dialog right?
this 
      
     showDialog(progress_bar_type);
and 

     dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

Just initiate the dialog within the async task itself not via outside method because you won't have that Instance outside the AsyncTask class

Comment: Yeah we'll try it and let you know